# Getting error while implementing multiple validation for input field in Angular4

Tags: javascript, angular

I am getting the following error while implementing the multiple validation for single input field using Angular4.

Error:

```
ERROR in src/app/about/about.component.ts(30,7): error TS1117: An object literal cannot have multiple properties with the same name in strict mode.
src/app/about/about.component.ts(30,7): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'url
```

Here is my code:

about.component.html:

```
<form [formGroup]="textForm" (ngSubmit)="onTextFormSubmit()">
<input type="text" placeholder="please enter url" formControlName="url" id="weburl"><label *ngIf="textForm.get('url').invalid && processValidation" [ngClass] = "'error'"> Url is required. </label>
<button type="submit">ADD</button>
</form>
```

about.component.ts:

```
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {
  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/json'});
  aboutData = [];
  processValidation = false;
  pattern="/^(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?$/";
  filePath:string;
  filelist: Array<{filename: string, intkey: string}> = [{
      filename: 'http://oditek.in/jslib/jslib.js',
      intkey: 'aboutlib'
      },{
      filename: 'http://oditek.in/jslib/aboutjs.js',
      intkey: 'aboutjs'
  }];
  textForm = new FormGroup({
      url: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      url: new FormControl('', Validators.pattern(this.pattern))
  });
  constructor(private router:Router,private route:ActivatedRoute,private http:Http) { }
  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    $('#title').attr('style','font-weight:bold');
    /*$.getScript(this.filePath,function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
        checkJS();
      }, 5000);
    })*/
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params=>{
      this.filelist.forEach(item => {
        let parampath=atob(params['filepath']);
        if(item.intkey==parampath)
          this.filePath = item.filename;
        else
          return;
      });
    });
    this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/articles').subscribe(
      (res:Response)=>{
        this.aboutData = res.json();
      }
    )
  }
  onTextFormSubmit(){
    this.processValidation = true;
    if (this.textForm.invalid) {
      return;
    } 
    let url = this.textForm.value;
  }
}
```

I need here the blank field and pattern validation for single input field. All respective error message will display below the input field but I am getting this error.

Comment: Note: the filenames in this question `about.componet.*` appear to have been misspelled, and I fixed them to `about.component.*` instead. Please amend them if they really were correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this code of yours:

```
textForm = new FormGroup({
      url: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      url: new FormControl('', Validators.pattern(this.pattern))
});
```

You do not need to add 2 controls of same name for just putting 2 validations. You can insert array of validators like following:

```
textForm = new FormGroup({
      url: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.pattern)])
});
```

Comment: yes, But I think that pattern is not validating for URL type input because if I am giving the input like `http//example.com` still the error message is showing.

Comment: IT will take too much time to make for angular4.

Comment: validator is not working.
I made a plnkr kind of a thing.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wqz9sb?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

You creation of `url` FormControl is wrong, because you dont need to create two controls. You should combine your validators:

**Solution 1:**

```
textForm = new FormGroup({
      url: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.pattern)]))
});
```

**Solution 2:**

```
textForm = new FormGroup({
          url: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.pattern)])
    });
```

Comment: Your modification showing error `i.e-expected 1 argument but got 2`.

Comment: @satya I updated my code for first solution. I forgot to add brackets []

Comment: Yes, but how the error will be shown in html page ?

Comment: @satya Check this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48658368/angular-reactiveform-error-handling-through-switch-case/48661095#48661095) about error handling in angular reactive forms. At this answer you will find an live demo.

Comment: @satya Here is a link to the demo with validation: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6gnxfx

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are creating a new control of url and two controls can't be created in a single form

```
this.formName.group({
      title: [null,[Validators.required,Validators.pattern(this.pattern)]],
})
```

Comment: I did like `textForm = new FormGroup({
      url: new FormControl('', Validators.required,Validators.pattern(this.pattern))
  });` this as per you still some error.

Comment: pass into the array not as function textForm = new FormGroup({ url: new FormControl('', [Validators.required,Validators.pattern(this.pattern))] });

Comment: please test might be like this

Comment: I did like `textForm = new FormGroup({ 
    url: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.pattern))]
  });` but showing error `, expected`.